# QVariant is not able to distinguish between QDateTime and QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qvariant, qdatetime

I have a `QDateTime object` which I store in a `QVariant` and then I check the `QVariant` with `type()` but it behaves strangely when I check the type.

```
void MainWindow::Test()
{

    QDateTime myDate; // QDateTime;
    myDate.setDate(QDate::currentDate());

    QVariant myVariant(myDate);
    qDebug() << myVariant.canConvert(QMetaType::QDateTime); // return true 

    // here is the problem
    qDebug() << myVariant.canConvert(QMetaType::QString); // return true as well
}
```

Comment: A date can be converted to a string, and that's what you asked, so what exactly is your problem? I don't see your code using `type()` at all, though, in spite of what you claim.

Answer (score 1):

`canConvert` means only that conversion is possible, not that variant contains specific type. To verify type use this approach:

```
qDebug() << (myVariant.type()==QVariant::DateTime);
qDebug() << (myVariant.type()==QVariant::String);
```